# Sequelize and Mysql throw connect ETIMEDOUT error In production enviroment

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, pm2

I have a nodejs server with express and sequelize. When I was in development enviroment I didn't have any problem then in production enviroment sometimes the entire app throw this error in everyrequest
`ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT` for a few minutes then the server starts to work normally.

In the server I use pm2 cluster mode(8 instances) to handle all the requests.

Is the first that I manage a server and a DB and I read some articles, I've tried changing mysql enviroment variables and the sequelize pool options but the problem persists.

I'm not sure if the problem is in the variables or the server specs or pm2 config. I hope someone can give a hint of the problem.

### mysql variables

```
skip_name_resolve = 1

join_buffer_size = 50M

tmp_table_size = 2G

max_heap_table_size = 2G

thread_cache_size = 40

max_connections=1600

key_buffer_size=195k

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G

innodb_log_file_size = 512M

key_buffer_size = 1M

innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
```

### sequelize configuration

```
{
    host: config.bd_host,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 1000000,
      idle: 100000,
      evict: 2000,
    },
    dialectOptions: {
      decimalNumbers: true,
    },
  }
```

### Server specifications

- 64gb RAM
- 16 cores proccesor
- ubuntu 18.04.5 lts
- mysql version 14.14 Distrib 5.7.40, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
- express 4.17.1
- sequelize 6.19.1
- node version 14.17.2